# Include mongocxx drivers with Cmake results with undefined methods on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, cmake, c++14, mongo-cxx-driver

I have an issue with linking libmongocxx in my project.

I am using CMAKE to link the library and I am running Ubuntu 17.10.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
    project(web_service_cpp)

    SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

    set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

    find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
    find_package(Hana REQUIRED)
    find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
    find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
    add_library(libmongocxx INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_property(TARGET libmongocxx PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${libmongocxx_INCLUDE_DIR})

    add_library(boost INTERFACE IMPORTED)
    set_property(TARGET boost PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

    include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
    include_directories("/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi")
    include_directories("/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi")
    include_directories("/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0")
    include_directories("/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0")
    include_directories("/usr/local/lib")

    include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp
            src/cMqttService.cpp
            src/cMongoDB.cpp
            src/cRepository.cpp)


    set(HEADER_FILES include/cRepository.h
                include/cMqttService.h
                include/cMongoDB.h
                include/main.h)


     add_executable(web_service_cpp
            ${HEADER_FILES}
            ${SOURCE_FILES})

    target_link_libraries(web_service_cpp ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(web_service_cpp ${LIBBSONXX_LiBRARIES})
```

I find it weird that I am getting this error since it use to work on macOS :

```
   [ 20%] Building CXX object 

    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o
    [ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMqttService.cpp.o
    [ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMongoDB.cpp.o
    [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cRepository.cpp.o
    [100%] Linking CXX executable bin/bin/web_service_cpp
    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMqttService.cpp.o: In function `cMqttService::initCommunication()':
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::async_client(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, mqtt::iclient_persistence*)'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::connect_options()'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x266): undefined reference to `mqtt::connect_options::connect_options(mqtt::connect_options const&)'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x286): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::connect(mqtt::connect_options)'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x3ca): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::publish(std::shared_ptr)'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x464): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::publish(mqtt::buffer_ref, void const*, unsigned long, int, bool)'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x4ea): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::~async_client()'
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text+0x63f): undefined reference to `mqtt::async_client::~async_client()'
    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMqttService.cpp.o: In function `mqtt::async_client::disconnect()':
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text._ZN4mqtt12async_client10disconnectEv[_ZN4mqtt12async_client10disconnectEv]+0x36): undefined reference to `mqtt::disconnect_options::disconnect_options()'
    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMqttService.cpp.o: In function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::construct, mqtt::buffer_ref, int&, bool&>(mqtt::message*, mqtt::buffer_ref&&, mqtt::buffer_ref&&, int&, bool&)':
    cMqttService.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4mqtt7messageEE9constructIS2_JNS1_10buffer_refIcEES6_RiRbEEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN4mqtt7messageEE9constructIS2_JNS1_10buffer_refIcEES6_RiRbEEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0xdc): undefined reference to `mqtt::message::message(mqtt::buffer_ref, mqtt::buffer_ref, int, bool)'
    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/src/cMongoDB.cpp.o: In function `cMongoDB::cMongoDB(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, short)':
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x63): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::instance()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::k_default_uri[abi:cxx11]'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::uri(bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value)'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::uri(bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value)'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::operator=(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri&&)'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::~uri()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::client(mongocxx::v_noabi::uri const&, mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client const&)'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x232): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::operator=(mongocxx::v_noabi::client&&)'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x241): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::~client()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x2e3): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::client::~client()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::~uri()'
    cMongoDB.cpp:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::~instance()'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'bin/bin/web_service_cpp' failed
    make[2]: *** [bin/bin/web_service_cpp] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/web_service_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am open to suggestions! 
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `LIBMONGOXX_LIBRARIES` is a typo: it should be  `LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES`. Also, do **never** set *CMAKE_BINARY_DIR* variable: many external and internal CMake functionality treat it as a pointer to the build directory (where `cmake` has been invoked).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I fixed my typo but it sadly didn't fixed my problem. I have also removed CMAKE_BINARY_DIR variable on your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem. It is caused by all those hard coded strings that I used back on macOS.

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(web_service_cpp)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(Hana REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_library(paho-mqttpp3 NAMES libpaho-mqttpp3.so REQUIRED)
find_library(paho-mqtt3a NAMES libpaho-mqtt3a.so REQUIRED)
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
add_library(libmongocxx INTERFACE IMPORTED)
add_library(libbsoncxx INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libmongocxx PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set_property(TARGET libbsoncxx PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(boost INTERFACE IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET boost PROPERTY
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(pahottpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(pahottpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${paho-mqttpp3})

add_library(pahomqtt3a SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET pahomqtt3a PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${paho-mqtt3a})

include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp
            src/cMqttService.cpp
            src/cMongoDB.cpp
            src/cRepository.cpp)


set(HEADER_FILES include/cRepository.h
                include/cMqttService.h
                include/cMongoDB.h
                include/main.h)



add_executable(web_service_cpp
        ${HEADER_FILES}
        ${SOURCE_FILES})

    target_link_libraries(web_service_cpp ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES} ${lIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES} pahottpp pahomqtt3a)`